# systemctl --state=failed

Tags: systemd

Good day. When Ubuntu 18.04.3 starts with the 5.2.8 kernel, the following error pops up:

```
systemctl --state=failed
     UNIT LOAD ACTIVE SUB DESCRIPTION
● ureadahead.service loaded failed failed Read required files in advance
```

What is this? How to fix it?

Thank you

Comment: The 5.2.8 kernel is not officially supported. There must be some incompatibility. But if everything works, you can ignore it. Mainline kernels may have different config.

Comment: ok thanks for help.
and say what is responsible for "ureadahead.service”?

Comment: Here is the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/ureadahead.8.html) for ureadahead, the error you are receiving has been [noted before](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ureadahead/+bug/1763584)

Comment: ureadahead is removed in later versions of Ubuntu... but if you upgraded Ubuntu, and had ureadahead before, it'll still be there. Start `synaptic` and see if ureadahead is default installed on your version of Ubuntu. If not, uninstall it.